# Question concerning the solution of a certain calendar problem involving modular arithmetic.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, calendar-computations

A question I was given is the following:

> A certain month on the calendar has 31 days, and it has an equal amount of Mondays and Wednesdays. How many different kind of days(Monday to Sunday) can be the starting day of this month?

I have drawn out each calendar scenario and gotten an answer of 3(Monday, Thursday, and Friday), but the solution gives an easier way:

> $31\equiv3\pmod7$, so the week cannot start with Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday or Wednesday as that would result in an unequal number of Mondays and Wednesdays. Therefore, Monday, Thursday, and Friday are valid so the answer is $\boxed {B\ }$. (*Source*: [AMC 12](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2010_AMC_12B_Problems/Problem_4))

I'm perplexed on how this works. How did they jump from $31\equiv3\pmod7$ to "the week cannot start with Saturday, Sunday, Tuesday or Wednesday"? Can someone explain to me how this works? Thanks.

Also, if you replaced Monday and Wednesday in the answer with a different pair of days, would the same approach work? Like will the following question also have an answer of 3?

> A certain month on the calendar has 31 days, and it has an equal amount of Tuesdays and Fridays. How many different kind of days(Monday to Sunday) can be the starting day of this month?

Comment: You should link this in your question for the original source: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2010_AMC_12B_Problems/Problem_4

Comment: @JamesHuang Ok the problem is from there but can you explain further how that solution works?

Answer (score 1):

It’s definitely not clear to begin a solution with $31\equiv3\pmod7$ without some context, so here's some.

Spoiler: The $3$ is the number of days in the month beyond as many full $7$-day weeks as the month contains. Call those days after as many full weeks in the month “leftover days.”

Two different weekdays appear the same number of times in the month so long as they are either both present or both absent in the “leftover” days. (The leftover days are those, if any, after the first $28$ days, for normal months with between 28 and 31 days.)

In the case of actual calendar months, there are always $4$ full weeks, plus between $0$ and $3$ additional days, but finding out what number modulo $7$ equals the number of days in the month is a completely general approach when there are $7$ days in a week.

So in this case, we first find $31\pmod7$, which is the number of “leftover” days. Of course, these leftover days must be consecutive, so for there to be the same number of Mondays as Wednesdays in three consecutive days, the possibilities are that the days are Monday-Wednesday, Thursday-Saturday, or Friday-Sunday. These are the only three ways the month can end without its having different numbers of Mondays and Wednesdays, so there are exactly three weekdays on which the month can begin. (This last deduction from ways a month can end to ways it can begin takes a bit of thought, but I hope it's not a mystery.)

Answer (score 0):

There has to be more to his explanation. Your conclusion of Monday, Thursday and Friday is correct because, in a $31$ day month, the weekdays that correspond to the first, second and third of the month occur five times while the other days of the week occur four times. We can easily see that we can start on Monday, Thursday or Friday because if we start on Monday, both Monday and Wednesday occur five times and if we start on either Thursday or Friday, they both occur four times. In all other cases, they occur a different number of times.

We can apply that same analysis to the case when we require the same number of Tuesdays and Fridays.

We can't start on Sunday, Monday or Tuesday because we would get five Tuesdays but only four Fridays. We can't start on Wednesday, Thursday or Friday because we would get five Fridays but only four Tuesdays. Therefore, we can only start on a Saturday.

Therefore, there is more to this problem than the fact that $31\equiv 3\text{ mod }7$

Comment: But the solution is from here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2010_AMC_12B_Problems/Problem_4, and the solution explanation is solely based on the fact that $31\equiv3\pmod7$. What I'm trying to understand is that how they concluded the answer based on that one fact. I'm also wondering how this specific solution approach would change if I changed the two days in which the number of days are the same to some other two days.

Comment: @AidenChow I looked at the original problem from the link provided by James Huang and it looks like the statement about the congruence relation is their way of saying that three consecutive days have five occurrences. If that's the case then their explanation is the same as mine.

Comment: But I'm perplexed as to how they used $31\equiv3\pmod7$ to conclude the answer. It just seems such a logical skip to me. I don't see any connection between their steps. Maybe you can explain their explanation further?

Comment: @AidenChow I believe that the congruence statement is also confusing in that it is overkill. The significance of the congruence is that no matter which day you start, all numbers will occur the same number of times except the first three. He then assumes each of us has the ability to verify the possibilities on our own.Notice how he states the congruence and then concludes the only possibilities.